# Determine planar phyllotaxis characteristics

Tags: botany, methods, flowers

Is there any method to fast and precise count the number of spiral and the divergence angle on a planar phyllotaxis pattern?

[image: The example of spiral phyllotactic arrangement of emerging flowers on Gerbera hybrida. (doi: 10.1093/jxb/erw489)]

The example of spiral phyllotactic arrangement of emerging flowers on Gerbera hybrida. (doi: 10.1093/jxb/erw489)

I'm looking for a method for characterizing any phyllotaxis pattern.

Comment: I've found a following protocol for counting spirals on sunflower heads: http://www.turingsunflowers.com/media/Resources/count/Measure_and_count.pdf